# Directive to hide elements of guest user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that could hide specific element for guest user. Currently I have this:

```
angular.module('someMod')
    .directive('premiumUser', premiumUser)
    .controller('PremiumUserCtrl', PremiumUserCtrl);

function premiumUser () {
    return {
        restrict   : 'A',
        link       : premiumUserLink,
        controller : 'PremiumUserCtrl',
    };
}

function premiumUserLink (scope, element) {
    if (!scope.checkLoggedIn())
        element.hide();
}

function PremiumUserCtrl ($scope, sessionManager) {
    $scope.checkLoggedIn = function () {
        return sessionManager.isUserLoggedIn();
    };
}
```

So when I apply this directive to an element like this:

```
<ANY premium-user></ANY>
```

it works, but it doesn't prevent the targeted directive's controller to initialize and execute onInit code.

How can I modify this directive to prevent controller initialization?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using something to handle routes? if your not, might be worth using something like (ui-router)[https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router].

Comment: @alphapilgrim Yes, I use it, how can it help me?

Comment: where the state is defined, state has a resolve method that can check a user type/credentials before the state change.

Comment: @alphapilgrim I'm using my directive to hide specific element within a route's template. Resolve could help me if I wanted to avoid guest user navigating to page for authenticated users only.

Comment: are you using angulars router or the defactor version?

Comment: @alphapilgrim I'm using ui-router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132540/discussion-between-alphapilgrim-and-xsaber).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, a ng-if should work. I think if you just use a scoped variable to check to its availability. then place the scope.var on directive tag in the template.

```html
<any premium-user ng-if="iSGuest"></any>
```

```
/ / ctrl

$scope.isGuest = function() {
  //processing for guest
};
```

Comment: Yep ng-if could help here, but it requires adding one more scope method to each controller where my directive is used. This is the main point why I want implement it with a directive.

Comment: @xSaber Might want to just use rootScope.userType and set it to check your user on the run block of that view or at any time stateChangeStart that way you'd set it once.

Answer (score 0):

`element.hide()` only sets the CSS property `display: none`, so any directives and their controllers will still initialize.

I would implement a custom `ng-if`-directive, something like this:

```
function premiumUser ($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 600,
        transclude: 'element',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
            if (scope.checkLoggedIn()) {
              var childScope;

              if (!childScope) {
                childScope = scope.$new();
                transclude(childScope, function(clone) {
                    $animate.enter(clone, element.parent(), element);
                });
              }
            }
        },
        controller: 'PremiumUserCtrl'
    };
}
```

Check out the [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) docs and source code if you're interested to know more about how it works.